# Problema con Trigger SQLSERVER 2019

Tags: sql-server, trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER ActualizarInventarioValorizado
ON existencias
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ultimoDiaDelMes DATE = DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(MONTH, 
  DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())+1,0));
  IF GETDATE() = @ultimoDiaDelMes
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @id_inventario TABLE (id INT);

    INSERT INTO InventarioValorizado (fecha, id_local, total)
    OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @id_inventario
    SELECT CAST(GETDATE()AS DATE), id_local, SUM(Disponible * costo) AS total
    FROM existencias e
    INNER JOIN productos p ON e.id_producto = p.id_producto
    GROUP BY id_local;
  
    DECLARE @id INT = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @id_inventario);

    INSERT INTO DetalleInventarioValor (id_inventario, id_producto, cantidad, precio,id_local)
    SELECT @id, e.id_producto, e.Disponible, p.costo,e.id_local
    FROM existencias e          
    INNER JOIN productos p ON e.id_producto = p.id_producto;
  END
END;
```

Tengo este trigger, que deberia almacenar el inventario valorizado al cierre de cada mes, para cada sucursal, guardando en el maestro la fecha, el id del local, el total valor, y en el detalle, el id del producto, el id del maestro inventario,el precio del producto, la cantidad, el problema es que al almacenar el registro del detalle, todos los registros los almacena con el ultimo id que genera en el maestro, lo que hace que no pueda distinguir de que local pertenece cada detalle

Comment: Me parece muy dificil que `IF GETDATE() = @ultimoDiaDelMes` esa condición se cumpla. Dado que getDate() te devolverá un datetime. Deberías de hacerle un cast as date. Además se supone que estás haciendo un trigger, para que cada vez que se modifique o inserte un registro de existencias, haga todo lo que expones. Y no trabajas con los registros que se insertan o modifican, sino con la tabla entera. donde dice `existencias e` debería de decir `inserted e`. Luego para tener una respuesta adecuada, deberías de exponer un escenario adecuado.

Comment: Un trigger no es el sitio adecuado para realizar el proceso que describes. Sería más adecuado hacerlo en un procedimiento almacenado, que luego puedes lanzar con un _job_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo que empezar diciendo que concuerdo con el comentario que menciona que un trigger no es el lugar adecuado para este proceso y debería ser un job que se ejecute solo una vez al mes en vez de que se ejecute cada vez que se actualicen las existencias. Además de la carga extra de existencias, tendrás filas duplicadas en caso de que actualices las existencias más de una vez en el último día del mes. Aunque como está escrito,nunca se ejecutará porque compara una fecha sin tiempo con una fecha con tiempo y nunca serán iguales.

Para hacer las cosas más reales, dejaré un procedimiento almacenado que puedes asignar para que se ejecute el último día del mes y puede ser lo más cercano a la media noche para que no haya cambios posteriores.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ActualizarInventarioValorizado
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @ultimoDiaDelMes DATE = DATEADD(ms,-3,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE())+1,0)),
          @Hoy             DATE = GETDATE(); --Guardamos la fecha de hoy por si estamos muy cerca de la medianoche y cambia el día

  IF @Hoy = @ultimoDiaDelMes
  BEGIN
    -- Eliminamos información que se haya guardado antes para este mes para evitar duplicados.
    DELETE DetalleInventarioValor 
    WHERE id_inventario IN( SELECT id 
                            FROM InventarioValorizado 
                            WHERE fecha = @Hoy);

    DELETE InventarioValorizado 
    WHERE fecha = @Hoy;

    -- Agregamos el local para saber a que fila corresponde cada id
    DECLARE @id_inventario TABLE (
        id          INT,
        id_local    int);

    INSERT INTO InventarioValorizado (
            fecha, 
            id_local, 
            total)
    OUTPUT  inserted.id, 
            inserted.id_local 
    INTO    @id_inventario
    SELECT  @Hoy, 
            e.id_local, 
            SUM(e.Disponible * p.costo) AS total
    FROM existencias e
    INNER JOIN productos p ON e.id_producto = p.id_producto
    GROUP BY id_local;

    INSERT INTO DetalleInventarioValor (
            id_inventario, 
            id_producto, 
            cantidad, 
            precio,
            id_local)
    SELECT  i.id, --utilizamos el id de la tabla que unimos por medio del local
            e.id_producto, 
            e.Disponible, 
            p.costo,
            e.id_local
    FROM existencias e          
    INNER JOIN productos p ON e.id_producto = p.id_producto
    INNER JOIN @id_inventario i ON e.id_local = i.id_local;
  END
GO
```